# I installed Windows only on a MBP, unable to boot from removable

Tags: macbook-pro

My Mac decided to go weird and got a kernel error and won’t boot anymore. Looking around in desperation mode I figured that maybe I could use that Bootcamp pendrive I once setup. Now it turns out it’s not compatible with my model (2017 tMBP) and while windows has installed successfully and I can use a usb mouse and keyboard nothing else works. I installed because I though I would be able to boot it, get online and then create a bootable Mac install from it. Perhaps more threatening is the fact that now the computer doesn’t boot from removable drives at all (including the flash drive I installed it from).  Would I be able to reinstall macOS?
I’m thinking that maybe I could get a bootable install shipped to me and reinstall Bootcamp from there?

Comment: Did you try to boot into Recovery Mode with Cmd-R?

Comment: Are you trying to install macOS, Windows or both? If Windows, which version? If you want to just install Windows, then you will need the Boot Camp Support Software. You can acquire this software by using the macOS Boot Camp Assistant application.

Comment: I have Windows installed. Recovery doesn’t work neither does any of the boot commands.